# Save Selenium Test Result in text file using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I have written Selenium automation test cases in visual studio using selenium web driver and made the test fail intentionally.I am able to see the test results in test explorer after it fails but not able to see the test results file in my local machine.How can i get the results as i have to read that and log in JIRA?

Comment: What test framework you are using? e.g. NUnit, MStest

Comment: MSTest i have used

Comment: i am able to see the results but the problem is when i run the test from visual studio then browser opens automatically and i can see all the test done but when i run from command line using MStest.exe in jenkins then browser is not opening ..any idea would be helpful